# Troubleshooting the spinning wait cursor or spinning disc pointer

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, logs

I have a mid 2009 MBP with Mavericks and am increasingly seeing the spinning wait cursor or spinning disc pointer - how do I try to troubleshoot what might be happening?
Indeed, in what situations does this object appear - are the situations purely internal in the sense of lack of CPU power or RAM or motherboard characteristics, or can external factors also impact such as HDD or network characteristics?
I presume that the spinner appears in response to the current application not to some background event, so, in troubleshooting I'd also presume you would need to look at logs of some sort of the current application and possibly of a general nature, things with which I'm not familiar.

Answer (score 1):

One would use the Activity monitor in your Utility folder to find out the Loads to the CPU, RAM or Disk.

On my MBA 10.9.4 it looks like this:

[image: activity]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I have just, belatedly, come across it!
The thing about using Activity Monitor is that it becomes the active application, so the application that might have been causing the spinning wheel is not now active, which is why I referred to looking at logs.

Comment: Not so on my Mac. The app that is stick in spin, will continue that even if another window is open. However, looking in the Console log one can look for waiting times or continuous retries. If it is a system wide (every app does it) then it could be caused by low RAM or CPU overload.